# I can't install "System.Threading.Thread 4.0.0" in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin.ios, nuget, nuget-package, xamarin-studio

I install a NuGet package of sqlite-net and this package create a class in the main project, SQLite.cs and this class use the "System.Threading.Thread" and I try to install the "System.Threading.Thread 4.0.0" from NuGet but i have an error:

> Adding System.Threading.Thread... Adding 'System.Threading.Thread
>   4.0.0' to AyVoy. Could not install package 'System.Threading.Thread 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'portable-net45+win+wp80+MonoTouch10+MonoAndroid10+xamarinmac20+xamarintvos10+xamarinwatchos10+xamarinios10',
>   but the package does not contain any assembly references or content
>   files that are compatible with that framework. For more information,
>   contact the package author.

Any idea of how I can install this package?

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of project did you create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to install System.Threading.Thread 4.0.0 which supports .NET Standard 1.3 into a Portable Class Library (PCL) project that targets Profile 78. This is not supported. None of the portable class library projects that use a packages.config file support .NET Standard 1.3.

The [PCL profile to .NET Standard mapping](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md) is [documented](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md):

- Profile7 ->  .NET Standard 1.1
- Profile31 -> .NET Standard 1.0
- Profile32 -> .NET Standard 1.2
- Profile44 -> .NET Standard 1.2
- Profile49 -> .NET Standard 1.0
- Profile78 -> .NET Standard 1.0
- Profile84 -> .NET Standard 1.0
- Profile111 ->    .NET Standard 1.1
- Profile151 ->    .NET Standard 1.2
- Profile157 ->    .NET Standard 1.0
- Profile259 ->    .NET Standard 1.0

Whilst .NET Standard is supported with recent versions of Xamarin Studio 6.0.2 and Mono 4.4.2 you cannot install System.Threading.Thread into a PCL project using the above profiles.

You can install the System.Threading.Thread NuGet package into a Xamarin.iOS or a Xamarin.Android project with the latest versions of Xamarin Studio and Mono.